# How to get the post of category

Tags: categories

I have created the 2 categories. And these two categories have child category, how can i get the post of the category when I clicked on the category title. Please guide me

Comment: just simple call category in menu, when u click category post automatic call in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    // Get the ID of a given category
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Category Name' );

    // Get the URL of this category
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
?>

<!-- Print a link to this category -->
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name">Category Name</a>
```

After you click on the Category Title link, it will take you to the page where it displays all  the posts under that category. Note: category.php, archive.php template files are responsible for the display, else index.php will be used.

Comment: I have included category.php, archive.php. It takes category.php but loop is not working, can u help me in that

Comment: I have created post in custom post type. Please guide me

Comment: If you are using custom post type, have you attached the category to it ? or any custom taxonomy/term ?

Go through the template hierarachy here and you can  modify the template loop. http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Can you paste the code ?

Comment: I created custom taxonomy, used as $args = array('taxonomy'           => 'product-categories',
  'walker'             => null,
    'title_li'           =>'',
    'type' =>'products'); ?>
<ul>
<?php 
wp_list_categories($args); ?></ul>

Comment: I solved the issue, I created taxonomy-product-categories.php. Now the loop working fine

Comment: Glad to hear that..  

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work   :)